# GUIでキーボードを押したときに反応する、ショートカットキーを作りたい

Tags: java

現在、Javaを使ってのGUI開発を行っています。
そこで、JButtonでキーボード上で「w」を押したときに、マウスカーソルでbuttonがクリックされたときと同じ反応になる、いわゆる「ショートカットキー」を作ろうとしていますが、やり方がわからずに、行き詰まっています。

---

**現状のコード：**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Main{
   public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyGUI");
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setSize(600,400);
       frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

       
       JButton button = new JButton("Click here or Press\"w\":)"); //ここのボタンでwを押せるようにしたい
       frame.getContentPane().add(button);
       
       
       JLabel label = new JLabel("クリックもしくはキーボード入力に反応しました。");
       frame.getContentPane().add(label);
       label.setVisible(false);
       
       button.addActionListener(e -> { //マウスカーソルだけでなく、キーボードにも反応してほしい
                label.setVisible(true);
            });
       
   }
}
```

---

少々コードが長くなり申し訳ございません。
ショートカットキーを作るには、どのようにすれば良いでしょうか。
また、GUIについては初心者なため、上記のコードでどこか直したほうがいいところ、改善、参考にすべきところなどありましたら、アドバイスをいただけると嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかもしれません。[How can we set the shortcut key to a JButton in Java?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-can-we-set-the-shortcut-key-to-a-jbutton-in-java), [How to add a shortcut key for a jbutton in java? \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33739623/9014308), [Keystroke/Hot Key for JButton in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30925438/9014308), [Create a keyboard shortcut for a button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16477549/9014308)

Comment: わざわざ海外のサイトなどからの取り寄せありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GUIでボタンを押したときに、文字の出力をしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/88304/2808) で説明した通り、Swing に関しては[公式チュートリアル](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)で解決することが多いです。

今回の場合は [shortcut で検索する](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F+shortcut)と、[How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) がヒットするかと思います。
(また、部分的な説明は前回のページ [How to Use the Common Button API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#abstractbutton) にもあるので、その説明に出てくる単語で検索することも可能でしょう。)

```java
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;


public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyGUI");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        final JLabel label = new JLabel("クリックもしくはキーボード入力に反応しました。");
        label.setVisible(false);

        final Action buttonClickedAction = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                label.setVisible(true);
            }
        };

        final JButton button = new JButton("Click here or Press\"w\":)"); //ここのボタンでwを押せるようにしたい

        button.addActionListener(buttonClickedAction);


        button.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('w'), "buttonClicked");
        button.getActionMap().put("buttonClicked", buttonClickedAction);

        frame.getContentPane().add(button);

        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

    }
}
```